# Django: Localize Date without Year

Tags: python, django, localization, date-formatting

Any idea how to localize a date, which should only displays day and month respectively month and day?

I know how to format the whole date:

```
formats.date_format(datetime.now(), format="DATE_FORMAT", use_l10n=True)
```

Which returns the date as: `Feb. 6, 2020` or `6 Feb. 2020` according to the locale setting.

I need the same Output, but without the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MONTH_DAY_FORMAT`.

```
formats.date_format(datetime.now(), format="MONTH_DAY_FORMAT", use_l10n=True)
```

Comment: As far as i know, this always returns ```'Feb 6``` and ignores the local order (e.g. ```6. Feb``` in Germany).

Comment: @T.Christiansen you are right. Try `MONTH_DAY_FORMAT` instead.